# ActionBarSherlock and appcompat_v7

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I have had an old application project that uses ActionBarSherlock. I have found it, and made a few changes to it. Now, I need to add new activities to the project, but when I try to do so, eclipse give me a lot of errors. The reason behind the errors is - I think - that the ActionBarSherlock and appcompat_v7 is interfering with each other as they are using the same resources. So my question is: Is there any way I can add new activities to my project without importing the new support library? (if I add them manually or copy them, they won't be in Manifest.xml)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is: Is there any way I can add new activities to my project without importing the new support library?

Sure. Just don't use the new-activity wizard. Create the Java class the way you would any other Java class. Create the resources the way you would any other resources. Add the `<activity>` element to the manifest manually. And you're set.

Comment: Isn't there any additional file that I need to modify if I make the activity manually?

Comment: @TamasKoos: So long as you have the manifest entry pointing to the Java class, everything else is up to you, based on what the activity needs to do.